# mudar cor so de elemento clicado

Tags: jquery

Preciso mudar a cor só do elemento que foi clicado, no caso mudar a cor de fundo da div - essa mesma e clonada varias vezes criando mais div no html dependendo do quanto é preciso - em todos os casos que fiz usando parent e siblings não obtevi sucesso , todas permanecem mudando de cor, preciso que so a div clicada mude de cor, e as demais permanei com a cor padrão.

```
     **Icon**
   <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
    <i class="taskIcon glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">
    </i>
    </a>

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default task">
            <div class="panel-heading  taskToDo">
                <span class="col-sm-8 taskTitle">
                    <span class="checkTask"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    descricao
                </span>
    </div>
       </div>
          </div>
       JS
       $(".taskIcon").on("click", function () {
       $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
       $(".boxTipoDeAtividade").hide();
       $(".taskAtividades").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down"); 
       **$(".taskToDo").addClass("taskToDoBackground");**
       });
       CSS 
       .taskToDoBackground{
       background-color: #efefef !important;
        }
```

Comment: Tentou passar por parâmetros? Tipo: `function (numerar por exemplo os botões )` o `onClick`? Botão 1 onclick - muda cor do parâmetro específico.

Comment: Marcelo, podes mostrar o elemento pai de `<div class="taskToDo">`?

Comment: postei o restante

Comment: Agora ficou ainda mais confuso. Existe algum pai comum entre `<a>` e `. taskToDo`? esse HTML repete-se várias vezes na página certo?

Comment: sim repete varias vezes

Comment: Vi que removeste a outra pergunta. Ia responder mas ela sumiu :)

Comment: Existe algum pai comum entre `<a>` e `. taskToDo` que obedeça a essa repetição?

Comment: ia reformular, no entanto achei que nao se adequou corretamente, desculpe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).closest(".taskToDo").addClass("taskToDoBackground");
```

Quando você faz o $(".taskToDo"), esse seletor retorna todos os elementos com essa classe. você tem que usar o .closest() pra retornar apenas o primeiro elemento mais proximo.