# Como alterar a cor apenas do elemento clicado?

Tags: javascript

Essa pergunta é semelhante ao [mudar cor so de elemento clicado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252933/mudar-cor-so-de-elemento-clicado) a diferença é que é usado Jquery e eu preciso de JS puro, eu tenho alguns elementos `<summary>` e quando eu clicar no elemento `<summary>` atual ele mude de cor no caso vermelho quando eu clicar em outro elemento `<summary>` (ou seja deixar de clicar no elemento `<summary>` atual) o anterior (que era o atual) volte com a cor original (preta):

```js
const summary = document.querySelectorAll('summary');

for (let i = 0; i < summary.length; i++) {
    summary[i].onclick = () => {
        summary[i].style.color = 'red';
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <details>
        <summary>Title 1</summary>
        <ul>
            <li>Content 1</li>
            <li>Content 2</li>
            <li>Content 3</li>
        </ul>
    </details>
    <details>
        <summary>Title 2</summary>
        <ul>
            <li>Content 1</li>
            <li>Content 2</li>
            <li>Content 3</li>
        </ul>
    </details>
</body>
</html>
```

Os elementos `<summary>` até muda de cor só que se clicar em todos ambos vão ter a cor e eu não sei como verificar o elemento `<summary>` que foi clicado anteriormente para que ele mude para a cor original ou seja no caso para mim verificar os elementos que foram clicados foi fácil, mas e os que não foram?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer isso com classes. Adicionando e removendo com `el.classList.add(` e `.remove(`. Mas já que estás a fazer diretamente na propriedade do elemento o que te falta é, dentro de um loop, repor valores a cada click.

A idea é criar uma variável que se lembre do elemento que recebe o `onclick` e depois correr um `for` com todos os elementos dentro da callback do click. Dentro desse `for` verificas quando o `sumary[j]` é o mesmo que o `el` que foi clicado e dás-lhe a cor certa.

Exemplo:

```js
const summary = document.querySelectorAll('summary');

for (let i = 0; i < summary.length; i++) {
  const el = summary[i];
  el.onclick = () => {
    for (let j = 0; j < summary.length; j++) {
      const color = summary[j] === el ? 'red' : 'inherit';
      summary[j].style.color = color;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <details>
    <summary>Title 1</summary>
    <ul>
      <li>Content 1</li>
      <li>Content 2</li>
      <li>Content 3</li>
    </ul>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary>Title 2</summary>
    <ul>
      <li>Content 1</li>
      <li>Content 2</li>
      <li>Content 3</li>
    </ul>
  </details>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfeito amigo! era justamente isso, obrigado ajudou muito.

Comment: Só que está sendo comparado todos os elementos ou um em específico?

Comment: @felipecardozo a cada clique o código percorre todos os elementos e muda a cor de cada um. Dentro do loop ele verifica se o item iterado é o que foi clicado e a esse específico dá a cor `red`

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa (com limitações, já veremos a seguir) é, sempre que clicar em um `summary`, procure se já existe um vermelho (e caso exista, mude a cor de volta para a original), e depois mude a cor do elemento clicado para vermelho:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('summary')
    .forEach(s => s.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        const vermelhoAtual = document.querySelector('summary[style="color: red;"]');
        if (vermelhoAtual) vermelhoAtual.style.color = 'inherit';
        s.style.color = 'red';
    })
);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <details>
        <summary>Title 1</summary>
        <p>Content 1</p>
    </details>
    <details>
        <summary>Title 2</summary>
        <p>Content 2</p>
    </details>
    <details>
        <summary>Title 3</summary>
        <p>Content 3</p>
    </details>
    <details>
        <summary>Title 4</summary>
        <p>Content 4</p>
    </details>
</body>
</html>
```

Como a ideia é que somente um `summary` por vez pode ser vermelho, não precisaria fazer um *loop* por todos, como sugeriu a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/464086/112052) (que é uma alternativa mais geral, caso tivesse a possibilidade de ter mais de um elemento vermelho, aí faria mais sentido percorrer todos e mudar a cor um a um - se bem que bastaria trocar [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) por [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) no código acima, para buscar somente os elementos vermelhos).

Enfim, se é garantido que somente um elemento será vermelho por vez, basta buscar por ele, usando o seletor `'summary[style="color: red;"]'`, e mudar a cor caso ele exista.

---

Mas como já dito no início, esta solução é um pouco limitada.

A limitação é que isso só funciona se o elemento não tiver outros estilos *inline*. Por exemplo, se tiver `style="font-weight: bold; color: red;`, ou até mesmo se tiver `style="color: red"` (sem o ponto-e-vírgula), o seletor já não pega mais o elemento.

Daria até para contornar com `document.querySelectorAll('summary[style*="color: red"]')` (repare no `*=` em vez de apenas `=`, [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/412219/112052) alguns exemplos e a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) para mais detalhes), mas aí talvez seja melhor usar classes e buscar pelos elementos que possuem aquela classe, por exemplo.

Uma outra alternativa é guardar o elemento vermelho, assim não precisamos buscá-lo toda hora (novamente, assumindo que não pode ter mais de um vermelho ao mesmo tempo):

```js
var vermelhoAtual = undefined;

document.querySelectorAll('summary')
    .forEach(s => s.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if (s == vermelhoAtual) return; // cliquei no mesmo elemento, não precisa fazer nada
        if (vermelhoAtual) vermelhoAtual.style.color = 'inherit';
        s.style.color = 'red';
        vermelhoAtual = s;
    })
);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <details>
        <summary>Title 1</summary>
        <p>Content 1</p>
    </details>
    <details>
        <summary>Title 2</summary>
        <p>Content 2</p>
    </details>
    <details>
        <summary>Title 3</summary>
        <p>Content 3</p>
    </details>
    <details>
        <summary>Title 4</summary>
        <p>Content 4</p>
    </details>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Boa, resposta! gostei da primeira possibilidade.